# Cannot open .py file in Google Virtual Machine SSH Terminal

Tags: python, ssh, google-compute-engine

I cannot open .py file through Google VM SSH Console. Kwrite and sudo apt-get install xvfb  are installed.

My command:

kwrite test.py

I get the following error:

kwrite: Cannot connect to X server.

Do I need to change the command/install additional software?

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `echo $DISPLAY` on the VM? Are you using `ssh -X` (upper-case)? See also [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12755/67311).

Answer (score 1):

X-Windows (X11 nowadays) is a client-server architecture. You can forward connections to **your** x server with a `-X` (uppercase) option to ssh (ie $ ssh -X username@server.com). This should work if everything is installed correctly on the server (apt-get usually does a good job of this, but I don't have a lot of experience with kwrite).

**EDIT**

from the ssh man page

> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the user's X authorization
>                database) can access the local X11 display through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.
>
> For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y option and the
>                ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for more information.

and the relevant `-Y`

> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

Comment: Thanks. The struggle is when using Google VM SSH Console... It throws an error when called with ssh -x

Comment: @iLoveTux @donei01 – I think you want `-X` (upper case, enables X11 forwarding), not `-x` (lower case, disables X11 forwarding).

Comment: @MishaBrukman, You are correct. I've updated my answer. I also added a security warning I was (ashamedly) unaware of regarding X11 forwarding.